# Google Sheet Timekeeping formulation

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I having a problem in Google pivot formulation, basically, I have a raw data from Biometrics (See image sample attached) and I'm trying to transpose the data into a more visual report, However, upon using the Pivot I can get the Min (Time-in) and Max (Timeout) but I can't show the Break in/out. Any google function that can help me out here? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hello here's the copy of my file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PbH_6xnWwnIb4SK7FM9L8AgYI4gvTr9TMme-KKEHEuc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

## A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(DeviceRaw!B2:C, 
 ISODD(COUNTIFS(DeviceRaw!B2:B, DeviceRaw!B2:B, 
 ROW(DeviceRaw!B2:B), "<="&ROW(DeviceRaw!B2:B)))))
```

## C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER({DeviceRaw!C2:C, DeviceRaw!F2:F}, 
 ISEVEN(COUNTIFS(DeviceRaw!B2:B, DeviceRaw!B2:B, 
 ROW(DeviceRaw!B2:B), "<="&ROW(DeviceRaw!B2:B)))))
```

## E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(C2:C-B2:B, "[hh]:mm:ss")))
```

## F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A="")+(B3:B-C2:C999<0),,TEXT(B3:B-C2:C999, "[hh]:mm:ss")))
```

## H2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:D, E1:F*1}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,sum(Col5),sum(Col6) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col4 
  order by Col4,Col1 
  label sum(Col5)'WORKED',sum(Col6)'NOT WORKED' 
  format sum(Col5)'[hh]:mm:ss',sum(Col6)'[hh]:mm:ss'", 1))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p8lTkKzT_t8uIMRORKAyKuV4Z0CGrFGuZbTu12WAoyo/edit#gid=1509705649)

Comment: Thank you for this, but my problem is to get the Break in and Break out.

Comment: My intended output is  Emp|Time-in|Break out |Break in|Time-out